# How to get day from JSON DarkSky swift

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift, nsdate

I want to make a weekly forecast in my Weather App (Sunday: , Monday: , etc...) So I am doing it with DarkSky but i've noticed something odd.

```
"daily": {
"summary": "Light rain throughout the week, with temperatures bottoming out at 48°F on Sunday.",
"icon": "rain",
"data": [
  {
   -> "time": 1453363200, <-
```

There is no value that says the day's name, only this property named 'time'. I assume it represents seconds but I am not sure how do I get the requested day. Like how do I determine a specific day from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative the the provided answers is to use a DateFormatter, which will take care of localisation as well, and it won't need to drop into DateComponents.

This is taken from a Playground

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1453363200) // -> "Jan 21, 2016, 8:00 AM"
let formatter = DateFormatter()

formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"

let day = formatter.string(from: date) // -> "Thursday"
```

If you want to see what other dateFormat strings there are you can see a really handy reference at http://nsdateformatter.com.

In general, though you want to avoid hard coding your date formats for presenting anything more than simple output such as this. in which case setting the date formatter's `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` properties is a much better way of presenting using visible dates that are culturally and locale appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The value represents a UNIX timestamp (seconds since 1/1/1970) you can create a date with:

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1453363200) // January 21, 2016 9:00 am
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the string into a `Date` format (from [vadian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45508312/7264964)):

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1453363200)
```

Then you can use `Calendar` to extract date components:

```
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday], from: date)
let weekday = components.weekday
```

The first argument to `dateComponents` takes an array of elements from the [`Calendar.Component` enum](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar.component).

For example if you wanted the hour, minute, second, and weekday you would do something like:

```
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second, .weekday], from: date)

let hour = components.hour
let minute = components.minute
let second = components.second
let weekday = components.weekday
// ...etc
```

#### Update

Note that `.weekday` returns an integer corresponding to the index of the day of the week (localized).

If you want the actual name of the day (e.g. Monday, Tuesday, etc.) you need to access `Calendar`'s `weekdaySymbols` property (which is also localized).

```
let weekdayName = Calendar.current.weekdaySymbols[weekday ?? 0]
```

(`weekday` is optional so I used a default value of `0`)